# Are qualifiers within the array declaration in function parameter lists an optional or mandatory feature in C17

Tags: c

Quoting the cppreference site

> In function parameter lists, additional syntax elements are allowed within the array declarators: the keyword static and qualifiers, which may appear in any order before the size expression (they may also appear even when the size expression is omitted).

and

> If qualifiers are present, they qualify the pointer type to which the array parameter type is transformed:

```c
int f(const int a[20])
{
// in this function, a has type const int* (pointer to const int)
}
int g(const int a[const 20])
{
// in this function, a has type const int* const (const pointer to const int)
}
```

However the snippet above won't compile on MSVC v19 using the `/std:c17` flag, failing wth the error:

```
<source>(5): error C2143: syntax error: missing ']' before 'const'
<source>(5): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before 'const'
<source>(5): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before 'const'
<source>(5): error C2059: syntax error: 'constant'
<source>(5): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
```

https://godbolt.org/z/8r9388PYn

Is this a MSVC bug or is this specification optional?

If this is a mandatory specification can you redirect me to the relative paragraph of the C17 standard?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Not so. "The /std:c17 option enables ISO C17 conformance." [Ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version)

Comment: @eric-postpischil This is EXACTLY what I was looking for, I still can't figure how you guys can find anything in the ISO specification so quickly, to me is just a huge mess where I can never find what I'm looking for. If you rewrite your comment as an answer I will acept it to close the thread.

Comment: btw.. the value `20` in `int f(const int a[20])` does not do anything and it is (or at least should) be ignored by the compiler. The proper way should be `int f(const int a[static 20])` to tell the compiler that `a` is pointer to at least 20 valid elements.

Comment: existing issue report link: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/c11-static-inside-array-parameter-square-brackets/1475168

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C standard requires a conforming C implementation to accept these qualifiers (C 2018 6.7.6 1 and 6.7.6.3 7). MSVC is not a conforming compiler.

6.7.6 1 shows the grammar for declarators, which includes:

- *direct-declarator* `[` *type-qualifier-list*<sub>opt</sub> *assignment-expression*opt `]`

There is no indication that this part of the grammar is optional.

6.7.6.3 7 specifies the interpretation of the qualifiers:

> A declaration of a parameter as “array of *type*” shall be adjusted to “qualified pointer to *type*”, where the type qualifiers (if any) are those specified within the `[` and `]` of the array type derivation…